# One Hot Encode Pandas Dataframe based on Column Headers

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have never done this before - and perhaps there's an easier way to do this.

**I have a df like this:**

```
parent_org_name (+MA,)  (MAR,)  (ART,)  (RTI,)  (TIN,)
0   +MARTINS    NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
1   111 SOUTH   NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN 
2   247 CUST    NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
3   3M          NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN 
4   A. K. ENT   NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
```

**Which I built by hand. I originally started with 2 dataframes:**

1: `df1` with just the `parent_org_name` as the only column

```
#df1
parent_org_name
0   +MARTINS
1   111 SOUTH
2   247 CUSTOMER PVT. LTD.
3   3M
4   A. K. ENTERPRISE
```

2: `df2` with all the column names (+MA, MAR, ART etc.) in one list in one column in one row

```
#df2
parent_trigram
0   [+MA, MAR, ART, RTI, TIN]
```

**I am trying to order the columns alphabetically and then one hot encode this `df` to say:**

```
if column name in df isin parent_org_name then 1 else 0
```

So this is the result I'm looking for:

```
parent_org_name (+MA,)  (ART,)  (MAR,)  (RTI,)  (TIN,)
0   +MARTINS    1        1       1       1      1
1   111 SOUTH   0        0       0       0      0   
2   247 CUST    0        0       0       0      0
3   3M          0        0       0       0      0   
4   A. K. ENT   0        0       0       0      0
```

The ultimate goal is to concat each of these rows into a column of lists, and then use that column in ml models.

Comment: This is str.contains

Comment: not sure if it helps but [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) - documentation

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'parent_org_name' : ["+MARTINS", "111 SOUTH", "247 CUST", "3M", "A. K. ENT"]
})

for c in ['+MA', 'MAR', 'ART', 'RTI', 'TIN']:
  df[c] = df['parent_org_name'].apply(lambda x: int(c in x))

print (df)
```

Output

```
parent_org_name +MA MAR ART RTI TIN
0   +MARTINS    1   1   1   1   1
1   111 SOUTH   0   0   0   0   0
2   247 CUST    0   0   0   0   0
3   3M          0   0   0   0   0
4   A. K. ENT   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i've come up with:

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)

mlb_df = df.join(
            pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(
                mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('parent_trigram')),
                index=df.index,
                columns=mlb.classes_))
mlb_df
```

Results in this:
[image]